# Is a SSL client required to try multiple certificate chains?

Tags: tls, certificates

Yesteday, 10 July 2019 I failed to access [dict.tu-chemnitz.de](https://dict.tu-chemnitz.de) with Epiphany (WebKit2, which is using GNUTLS) and mailed the administrator which fixed it quickly. Here is the access via GNUTLS:

```
$ gnutls-cli dict.tu-chemnitz.de
Processed 155 CA certificate(s).
Resolving 'dict.tu-chemnitz.de:443'...
Connecting to '134.109.133.9:443'...
- Certificate type: X.509
- Got a certificate list of 4 certificates.
- Certificate[0] info:
  - subject `CN=dict.tu-chemnitz.de,OU=Universitaetsrechenzentrum,O=Technische Universitaet Chemnitz,L=Chemnitz,ST=Sachsen,C=DE', issuer `CN=DFN-Verein Global Issuing CA,OU=DFN-PKI,O=Verein zur Foerderung eines Deutschen Forschungsnetzes e. V.,C=DE', serial 0x1ddeea4d08db829c1f1b3603, RSA key 2048 bits, signed using RSA-SHA256, activated `2017-09-18 06:50:38 UTC', expires `2020-12-15 06:50:38 UTC', pin-sha256="HPAyb8xUhT23hfPUC+J6sxeVlW8e4K8N3JOGE2pZZH8="
    Public Key ID:
        sha1:f43cd7f782e17d07c98de23c71d613d834dde868
        sha256:1cf0326fcc54853db785f3d40be27ab31795956f1ee0af0ddc9386136a59647f
    Public Key PIN:
        pin-sha256:HPAyb8xUhT23hfPUC+J6sxeVlW8e4K8N3JOGE2pZZH8=

- Certificate[1] info:
  - subject `CN=DFN-Verein Global Issuing CA,OU=DFN-PKI,O=Verein zur Foerderung eines Deutschen Forschungsnetzes e. V.,C=DE', issuer `CN=DFN-Verein Certification Authority 2,OU=DFN-PKI,O=Verein zur Foerderung eines Deutschen Forschungsnetzes e. V.,C=DE', serial 0x1b63bad01e2c3d, RSA key 2048 bits, signed using RSA-SHA256, activated `2016-05-24 11:38:40 UTC', expires `2031-02-22 23:59:59 UTC', pin-sha256="2plWEFSbja5Tz0pERjlr4FL2fr0H4L48Rt0ZF3sKBEQ="
- Certificate[2] info:
  - subject `CN=DFN-Verein Certification Authority 2,OU=DFN-PKI,O=Verein zur Foerderung eines Deutschen Forschungsnetzes e. V.,C=DE', issuer `CN=T-TeleSec GlobalRoot Class 2,OU=T-Systems Trust Center,O=T-Systems Enterprise Services GmbH,C=DE', serial 0x00e30bd5f8af25d981, RSA key 2048 bits, signed using RSA-SHA256, activated `2016-02-22 13:38:22 UTC', expires `2031-02-22 23:59:59 UTC', pin-sha256="nKACHrGIK7Y2Rip247vWnOEfapF/v8H8rewd/Mzla8U="
- Certificate[3] info:
  - subject `CN=T-TeleSec GlobalRoot Class 2,OU=T-Systems Trust Center,O=T-Systems Enterprise Services GmbH,C=DE', issuer `CN=Deutsche Telekom Root CA 2,OU=T-TeleSec Trust Center,O=Deutsche Telekom AG,C=DE', serial 0x119c148cc1ac0e95, RSA key 2048 bits, signed using RSA-SHA256, activated `2016-04-25 09:01:39 UTC', expires `2019-07-09 23:59:59 UTC', pin-sha256="YQbA46CimYMYdRJ719PMGFmAPVEcrBHrbghA3RZvwQ4="
- Status: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate. 
*** PKI verification of server certificate failed...
*** Fatal error: Error in the certificate.
```

As you can see, last certificated expired at *2019-07-09 23:59:59 UTC* and therefore I wasn't able to access the page yesterday. DFN stands for *Deutsches Forschungs Netzwerk*, which translates to *German Research Network*.
I had not the time to wait until the scan of [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=dict.tu-chemnitz.de&s=2001:638:911:b01:134:109:133:9) finished yesterday, which is - of course - now fine. I remember, that SSLShopper and a service of 1&1 also reported the problem. On the other hand, Chrome and Firefox accepted the certificate on my computer. I'm careful about Chrome and Firefox, which both cache intermediate certificates and [silently  reuse](https://blogs.gnome.org/mcatanzaro/2015/01/30/mozilla-is-responsible-for-the-redhat-corpmerchandise-com-fiasco/) them when possible. Therefore I always test the validity of a certificate with Epiphany, GNUTLS or OpenSSL and external services.

It was explained to me, that the domain used a cross-certificate. **Does a cross-certificate imply multiple certificate chains? Is a SSL client required to try out more than one chain?**

PS: I recommend that dictionary, it's pretty good and comprehensive. There is also a desktop application. The admin is also friendly :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if the client is actually required to check all possible chains but I know that at least OpenSSL by default does not check all possible chains.

In the past it followed the chain send by the server until the end (ignoring any self-signed at the end) and then checked if it finds a root certificate in the trust store to complete the chain. This caused various trouble with cross-certificates, see [here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27826829/3081018).

Newer OpenSSL version (since 1.1.0) instead check at each step at the server provided chain if they have a locally trusted certificate which completes the chain it has so far.